# Timing cross domain page load time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to time the load time of another domain from the client side using JavaScript. I know that you can do this by using the "src" attribute of "script" and "img" tags, but I'm not sure how to get a callback once the load is finished (or once it failed).

Most solutions I've seen for loading external content are server-side, but I'm trying to do this on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a callback when the call is done and not really need to read the server response, you can use the `Onload` `OnAbort` `OnError` events of the `script` or the `img` tag.

```
var i=new Image(1,1);
i.src = url;
i.onload = function(){
  alert('load complete')
}; 
i.onabort = function(){
  aletrt('aborted')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery if you wish to determine programmatically when files have loaded - using the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method.

Otherwise, you can use the developer tools of all major browsers to see the load times of all images and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to attach an event listener to the `load` event of the element. Something like:

```
function imgLoaded(){
    //do something cool
}

var img = new Image;
img.addEventListener("load", imageLoaded, false);
```

You can see an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zRLHp/). The image is initially hidden via `display:none`, which means that it will not start to get fetched. Then, using JS, I create an Image object, attach an event listener to the `load` event, and then set its source to the same as the `img` tag's source. Once it is fully loaded, the `<img>` is displayed. And you'll see that it shows up immediately despite being a very large image -- that's because it was hidden until the load event fired.